# Rename to web.xml when packaging using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, maven

I have a J2EE application which has two **web.xml** files. One is called **web.live.xml** another is **web.dev.xml**. I am building this application with maven using profiles. So maven knows which file to choose when packaging.

I was wondering is it possible to make Eclipse use **web.dev.xml** when packaging my project and deploying it to Tomcat. This would be very useful because **web.dev.xml** sets some options which decrease start up time of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can designate the dev xml to be default (and name it web.xml). You can also have maven move (from a different folder) rather than rename.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Maven resources plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) and configure it with a property in the profile and use that property in the configuration of the filename.